# Resharper - How to "move to resource" to different cultures?

Tags: .net, wpf, resharper

I am using WPF, I noticed the function "move to resource" when I write a string at XAML.

All right, it works. But my application supports English and Portuguese languages.

How can I refactory to both resources?

Thanks.

Example:

```
<Label Content="My Text"/>
```

Now if I get the cursor to "My text" and press CTRL+SHIFT+R (refactory function), I have the "move to resource" option.

Comment: Please provide what you have tried as far as code.

Comment: in the resources file you normally also have resharper options to override the string in the other languages, no?

Comment: Yes, but it's not pratical enough. Isn't there a better way?